# Is there a way to set the initialValues using state with formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to set the initialvaluse in formik using values set in state with react hooks. I have the following below but it seems to not update , I have tried using enableReinitialize but that did not work. How can I set the initial values so that they are correct.

<Formik

```
              initialValues={ initialValues}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually using formik with useFormik() hook.
When i want to add initial values it should go like this.

```js
const SomePage = () => {
  const [someName, setName] = React.useState('Somebody');
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: someName
    }
    validationSchema: Yup.object(), // validation here
    onSubmit: (values) => {

    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={formik.handleChange} values={formik.values.name} />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You probably want to add `enableReinitialize: true` to the `useFormik`call.